# “There is not enough memory to complete the operation” when trying to run Microsoft Project 2019 v2012

Tags: windows-10, ms-office, ms-project, office-2019

I am getting the following error on a clean install, “There is not enough memory to complete the operation. To free up memory, close programs, projects, or windows you aren’t using, and then try again.” With Microsoft Project 2019 professional x64 under Windows 10 Enterprise x64 version 20H2 build 19042.1110.

I have tried the following (not necessarily in order) and I am never able to load the splash screen:

1. Reinstall office 2019 pro plus x64.
2. Reboot, then retry project.
3. Run project in safe mode.
4. Tried a different windows profile.
5. Tried Administrator.

I am completely out of ideas.

My system specs are as follows:

- **O/S**: Windows 10 Enterprise x64 version 20H2 build 19042.1110.
- **CPU**: i7 4930k
- **RAM**: 64 GB
- **HDD Space available**: 683 GB On a SSD.

The only thing I can even remotely think of is possibly the paging file. Which since windows was just barely installed, is non-existent.